How to continuously add bands to an image of an ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine
Consider the following code for Google Earth Engine:
var sample_list = ee.List([0, 1, 2, 3]);
var sample_bandNames = ee.List(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4']);

var sample_function = function(image) {
    var var1 = image.select('VAR1');
    var var2 = image.select('VAR2');

    for (var i = 0; i < sample_list.length; i++) {
        var temp = sample_list[i];

        var numer = temp.multiply(var1);
        var result = numer.divide(var2);

        image = image.addBands(result, [ee.String(sample_bandNames[i])]);
    }

    return image;
}

var img_collection = img_collection.map(sample_function);

I would expect the function to continuously add bands to every image of the image collection, but every time I print the image collection, the number of bands remains unchanged. How can I continuously add bands to each image of the image collection?

I can't believe the answer is simple.
The problem with my code is that the function never enters the loop because sample_list.length does not return a number, but rather a function, so no bands are added to the image.
I just replaced sample_list with [0, 1, 2, 3]--removing the ee.List()--and it worked!
